# US Registered Sex Offender Travel to UK

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas, passport-stamps, criminal-records

I'm a registered sex offender and have been for over 5 years. My conviction is a misdemeanor and also over 5 years old. My question is, can I travel to the UK, for a couple of weeks? I've heard of "spent convictions" but I won't be eligible for that for another few years. I know the US law of notifying the registering agency at least 21 days before I leave, but I can't find any information about the UK laws for travelers and if they let us in.

I also have an RSO stamp in my passport. Any thoughts on how that's handled when landing in LHR?

Any advice on travelling as a US citizen to the UK as a registered sex offender for 10-14 days?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no official information but I would recommend asking in the British embassy/ consulate whether you need a visa to visit.

Comment: The only thing I know is that it is highly recommended to get an entry clearence (visa) in advance when you have a criminal record, which OP has

Comment: @quarague Pointless. UK embassies do not provide any information on visa requirements.

Comment: Should one assume that 'RSO stamp in my passport' is that what is meantioned here? [Passports and International Megan's Law - U.S. Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/legal-matters/passports-and-international-megans-law.html)

Answer (score 9):

This is an expansion of Nicolas' comment.

In general, if you have criminal record of any sort, then apply for a visa for that country, and DO NOT LIE on your application.

For the [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) page, if you plug in visitor from the USA, and for tourism, it eventually says you can travel visa free.  However, it adds the following caveat:

> You may want to apply for a Standard Visitor visa if you have a
> criminal record or you’ve previously been refused entry into the UK.

Note that the [Visit the UK as a Standard Visitor](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/apply-standard-visitor-visa) page says:

> The earliest you can apply is 3 months before you travel.

and

> Once you’ve applied online, proved your identity and provided your
> documents, you’ll usually get a decision on your visa within 3 weeks.

Which is actually a bit misleading, as they also say

> Visit visas, including standard visitor visa applications, are
> currently taking on average 6 weeks to process, however some
> applications might take longer. We are working hard to process
> applications to get back to the 3-week service standard.

Finally, it also says:

> As part of your online application, you need to book an appointment at
> a visa application centre.

---

And finally, finally.  Having a visa is not a 100% guarantee of being admitted to the UK.  The agents of the UK border force will have the final say about letting you into the country when you arrive on and show them the visa in your passport.  They have the power to deny you entry.

Comment: If you have a visa the chances of not being admitted are extremely low. It would basically be only if Immigration had discovered something about you since the visa was granted, or you did or said something at the border to make them think you had lied.

Comment: @DJClayworth But the chances of being refused entry are still non-zero.  And ".. make them think .." is deliciously ambiguous.

Comment: There is a non-zero chance that an asteroid will destroy the Earth while you are waiting at the border.

Comment: The UK does however make explicit statements about the weight of a visa that other countries explicitly disclaim.  UK immigration officers are somewhat more limited in their ability to refuse entry to someone who has a visa that are those in most other countries.